# Checkbox binding unwanted values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have a check box:

```
<td class="text-center">
    <div data-strat-form-control data-field-display-id="20" data-vmformreadonly="formReadOnly" data-show-tool-tip="showToolTip(contract.fields[5].htmlName)" data-strat-model="contract" data-field="contract.fields[5]"></div>
</td>
```

When clicked it is changing some field values. The 2nd and 3rd column change to N, 12.

I tried adding `bind-once` to the div and there was no effect. Then I tried `ng-non-bindable` and the checkbox dissapears.

How can I get this checkbox not to have an effect?

[image]

Comment: I don't see no checkboxes!

Comment: lol screenshot was from without the directive. I'll edit.

Comment: I feel like there's a lot that could be going on here, and I'm not sure if I have the context to figure it out